# Can I hide my legacy surname?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I gather that getting a legacy in SWTOR bestows a last name on your character.  I didn't really realize this when I made my character so the surname I'd like doesn't really fit with my character name.  Can I choose to not display my surname (while still, presumably, having a legacy)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can, it's in the options under Social → Legacy → Legacy Display.

There are three choices:

1. Hide Legacy:

   [image: Lord Svick]
2. Legacy Surname:

   [image: Lord Svick Lippert]
3. Legacy Title:

   [image: Lord Svick, The Lippert Legacy]

Legacy Surname is the default value.

Comment: Not anymore - it has been moved to your character sheet, under the titles button (upper left).